# Convert $\lnot(x \oplus y \oplus z\oplus a)$ to CNF

Tags: logic, normal-forms

How to convert the below formula to [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)?

> $\lnot(x \oplus y \oplus z\oplus a)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Tseitin transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin-Transformation).  It is a standard way to convert to CNF.  It introduces additional variables, but keeps the number of clauses and variables relatively small.

You can also use [very simple methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Conversion_into_CNF) using De Morgan's laws (or [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) or [the Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm)) to find an equisatisfiable CNF that does not introduce any new variables, but in general this will cause an exponential increase in the size of the CNF, which usually is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1

Find all the cases that makes the function to be false. In our case we can just find all the *truth* of that formula:

> $x \oplus y \oplus z\oplus a$

I will write it down from left to write, from $x$ - $a$, 1 for *true* 0 for *false*.

```
0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
```

Those will be the false cases for the main formula.

### Step 2

Now to get the **CNF** all what you have to do is to write them down with *not*. Because all the laterals connected with or signs, if we didn't wrote it down it will be true. So this is the **CNF** for that expression.

- $(\lnot x \lor \lnot y \lor \lnot z \lor a)$
- $(\lnot x \lor \lnot y \lor z \lor \lnot a)$
- $(\lnot x \lor y \lor \lnot z \lor \lnot a) $
- $(\lnot x \lor y \lor z \lor a)  $
- $(x \lor \lnot y \lor \lnot z \lor \lnot a) $
- $(x \lor \lnot y \lor z \lor a)  $
- $(x \lor y \lor z \lor \lnot a)$

In general this trick will work if all the variables appear in all the clauses.

Comment: This will be exponential in the size of the formula. There is a satisfiability but not model equivalent Tseitin transformation which is more efficient.

Comment: @VijayD Oh. Can you optimize this then? And can you link about it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin-Transformation

Comment: I think you need to justify the implicit claim that an $O(2^n)$-time algorithm is "fast".

Comment: This isn't a particularly new insight; first semester students do this in their fourth week or so. You can assume that anywhere this is useful, it is being applied.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It took me some time, but I just blogged  about it. You are welcome to [read](http://tsp-vs-world.blogspot.co.il/2013/11/convert-circuit-sat-to-k-sat-de-morgans.html).

Comment: @Babibu Your blog post just says, "It will take $2^n$ to build it, and while it seems like a lot, this is actually a very fast way." That doesn't justify the claim at all: it just states it as a fact a second time. The first time, you implicitly said "it's fast"; now, you're explicitly saying, "it's very fast." It still needs justification.

Comment: @DavidRicherby $2^N$ is a constant time. Lets say you have 100 variables and 1000 clauses, that you want to convert to K-SAT. You can do it by creating only $100 / (2^c)$ variables where $c$ is just the max size of your truth table(number of variables on the truth table). And it will take you $O(2^cN)$ time. Where n is the number of variables. I think you didn't read my blog to the end...

Comment: @Babibu $2^n$ is not fast in any conventional sense. If $n$ is the number of variables, then any truth table will have at least $n\cdot 2^n$ entries, and that's just the columns for the variables alone. Also, the claim that you can build an equivalent CNF for any formula in time linear in the number of variables is unsubstantiated, and you can't prove it because it's false, there are formulas for which any equivalent CNF has exponential length.

Comment: @G.Bach Now that you are saying this I think you are right. But never than less it's yet much more efficient and easy to code than De Morgan's laws - in terms of conversion to cnf.

Comment: If De Morgan or Karnaugh Maps are too complicated to implement, you can use Quine–McCluskey. It has a similar runtime as your approach, but gives a much more compact CNF representation - in fact, can provide the minimal CNF representation of a formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm