# Reduction of Circuit Satisfiability to CNFSAT

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

CNFSAT is Karp reducible to Circuit-SAT by replacing all the conjunctions with AND gate, disjunctions with OR gate and negations with NOT gate. However, if we apply the same approach to Karp reduce Circuit-SAT to CNFSAT, it may result in an exponential algorithm but the instance map should be done in polynomial time.

**How should we approach it then?**

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41070/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/38303/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18190/755 for more in this vein.

Answer (score 2):

The exponential blowup when converting circuits to conjunctive normal form is avoided by introducing new variables to represent the output of each sub-circuit plus a simple set of rules represent each sub-circuit and force their output into the variables (see [Tseitin transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseitin_transformation)).  The size of the resulting CNF formula is linear to the size of the circuit, and grows linearly as the circuit size is increased.